# How to embed YouTube videos into Flutter app to start from a specified timestamp?

Tags: flutter, dart, youtubeplayer, youtube-player-flutter

If you click on a YouTube video besides letting you copy the link, YouTube lets you to copy the link to start from the current time of playing. How can I do that on Flutter with YouTube embedded videos?

I used [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) and used YouTube URLs instead of video IDs, but even if I add a timestamp to the end of the links it still starts from the beginning. Is it possible to do it with this plugin? Is there another plugin capable of doing that?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      title: 'Flutter Example',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String videoId = 'BBAyRBTfsOU';

  static int startTime = 150;

  static String youtubeUrlWithStartTime =
      'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$videoId&t=$startTime';

  final YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: videoId,
    flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
      autoPlay: true,
      mute: false,
    ),
  );

  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter and Youtube'),
      ),
      body: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        liveUIColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startAt` property in your `YoutubePlayerFlags` for that.

https://pub.dev/documentation/youtube_player_flutter/latest/youtube_player_flutter/YoutubePlayerFlags/startAt.html

> **startAt** property.
> int startAt.
> final.
> Specifies the default starting point of the video in seconds
>
> Default is 0.

Comment: Thanks, I set it up. Now my problem is I can not use more than one video in a tab which I want to scrollable from one video to the next. None of the ways to have a list view word for me.

Comment: That doesn't sound like this was related to the initial issue that you asked about here at all though(?), so you should ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I shared incorrect information last time.

I got this concept to work using a `WebViewWidget()` and `ListView.builder()`, making sure to define the WebView controler inside the builder method. I also had to use the embed urls rather than the regular share urls from YouTube.

Here's a working example that renders videos in a list view, where the videos start at 10, 92, and 110 seconds, respectively (Flutter 3.13.6 stable; worked on iOS emulator and physical iPhone running iOS 17.1):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoApp({super.key});

  @override
  VideoAppState createState() => VideoAppState();
}

class VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {

  final List<String> videoEmbedUrls = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/embed/_o7qjN3KF8U?si=M0yo4R94r_NaVjyQ&amp;start=10',
    'https://www.youtube.com/embed/y8OnoxKotPQ?si=EmT_Ellfthq1ORcq&amp;start=92',
    'https://www.youtube.com/embed/eSqexFg74F8?si=pi77XZW6oI4rbw_9&amp;start=110'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Vehicle Data Entry')),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var wvController = WebViewController()
              ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
              ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
              ..setNavigationDelegate(
                NavigationDelegate(
                  onProgress: (int progress) {
                    // Update loading bar.
                  },
                  onPageStarted: (String url) {},
                  onPageFinished: (String url) {},
                  onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
                  onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) => NavigationDecision.navigate,
                ),
              );
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                child: WebViewWidget(controller: wvController..loadRequest(Uri.parse(videoEmbedUrls[index])))
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```